# How to push files in FileList?

Tags: javascript

My folder hierarchy looks like this:

- a/a.XML
- a/b/b.XML

I will select the `a.XML` file and read it. Now I have path of `b.XML` file.

My question is how to push this file in a `FileList` as I am not getting it through `<input type="file">`, since  I only have the files path. I have searched for a solution, but I didn't found any help how to push a file in a `FileList` without it's input tag. I want my code to be run in google chrome.

My current code for reading `a.XML` file through an input tag looks like this:

```
if(filePath.files && filePath.files[0]) 
{           
    reader.onload = function (e) 
    {
        output = e.target.result;
        console.log("file path"); 
        console.log(output);
    }
}
```

If `b.xml` is placed in the `FileList`, then I can easily read this file so I only have `b.xml` path and I want to push this file in `FileList` interface.

Comment: You can not randomly read just any file you like from the client. The user _has_ to chose that file first.

Comment: hello sir user choose a file i can get encrypted path of that file and on this base i can read all files placed on that path

Comment: @MuneemHabib This might help: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileList

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible to add paths to a `FileList` because of security issues.